# Checking values in 32-bit and 64-bit registries from x64 application?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I'm writing code that need to check whether a program is installed, and if so, get the path.  The path is stored in either

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Some\Registry\Path\InstallLocation
```

or

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Some\Registry\Path\InstallLocation
```

depending on whether the 32-bit or 64-bit flavor of said program is installed.

The code I have right now fails to find the path for a 32-bit installation when running on a 64-bit machine:

```
const string topKeyPath = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE";
const string subLocationPath = @"Some\Registry\Path\InstallLocation";

object pathObj = Registry.GetValue(topKeyPath + @"\" + subLocationPath, null, null);

if (pathObj == null) // if 32-bit isn't installed, try to find 64-bit
{
    try
    {
        RegistryKey view32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
        view32 = view32.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
        view32 = view32.OpenSubKey(subLocationPath);

        pathObj = view32.OpenSubKey(subLocationPath, false).GetValue(null);

        if (pathObj == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Not installed.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Not installed.", e);
    }
}

string installPath = Convert.ToString(pathObj);
```

Comment: Is you app compiled for AnyCPU target platform (without Prefer 32bit flag)?

Comment: My test code is compiled for AnyCPU, but I'm not sure what combinations the eventual software will target.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by refactoring my code into something cleaner and more logical.

```
        string installPath = GetInstallLocation(RegistryView.Default); // try matching architecture

        if (installPath == null)
        {
            installPath = GetInstallLocation(RegistryView.Registry64); // explicitly try for 64-bit
        }

        if (installPath == null)
        {
            installPath = GetInstallLocation(RegistryView.Registry32); // explicitly try for 32-bit
        }

        if (installPath == null) // must not be installed
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Program is not instlaled.");
        }
```

---

```
    public static string GetInstallLocation(RegistryView flavor)
    {

        const string subLocationPath = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Some\Registry\Path\InstallLocation";
        object pathObj;

        try
        {
            RegistryKey view32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, flavor);
            view32 = view32.OpenSubKey(subLocationPath);

            pathObj = view32.GetValue(null);

            return pathObj != null ? Convert.ToString(pathObj) : null;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```